# SIM7600SA 4g module to ESP32

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, communication, design, esp32

I am in a middle of getting the required components for my project. I will be using ESP32 microcontroller and SIM7600SA module for 4g/lte.. Since, I am a beginner in this field, can someone suggest if it is possible to connect sim7600sa to esp32. If yes, How can this be done?

Secondly, I cant find sim7600sa module online, all I can find is a chip - if I buy the chip, how can I hook it up with a sim jack and connect it to the controller?

I know the question is quite basic but want to be sure if this can be done or not.

Thanks,

Comment: Zohair, Welcome and nice to meet you I have a couple of answer in Rp SE, on SIM800/900/7600: Ths is a recent one:  "3 SIM800c GSM Hat on 1 raspberry pi 3b+": https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/using-3-sim800c-gsm-hat-on-1-raspberry-pi-3b. You can search SIM800, SIM900, SIM7600 for more answers. As you will see from those answers, the main interface between mcu/sbc such as arduino/rpi/esp etc are just series/UART, default 9600N81. One important thing for newbies is to do ***serial loopback***, before using ***AT*** text commands to start talking. Good luck. Cheers,

Comment: If it’s difficult to get the module itself why would you want to use it? I’m sure there are other popular modules that would do the job. Most SIM modules would have UART or other standard protocols to communicate with peripherals such as MCUs. The chip data sheet should tell you how that works. Very often they also have a reference schematic.